# SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verification failed

Tags: php, ssl, nginx

I started receiving error messages a few days and the problem was pointed to this code.

```
  function doUpload( $cid, $item )
 {
   $torrent = tempnam( '/tmp', 'articles' );

   $handler = fopen( $articles, 'w' );

   $fgetfiles = file_get_contents( ( string ) $item -> enclosure -> attributes() -> url);

   fwrite( $handler,  $fgetfiles );

   fclose( $handler );    

   $description = ( string ) $item -> description;
```

The error messages I received were

```
file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in line 77
```

the line 77 is shown below

```
$fgetfiles = file_get_contents( ( string ) $item -> enclosure -> attributes() -> url);
```

So this were the changes I made after I got this error:

1. I downloaded a CA_Bundle cert and added the path inside php.ini
   Restarted the server and run the code again but error was still there..
2. I disabled verification of SSL, by adding the code below, but that failed as well.

   > curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
3. Enabled SSL Verification by adding the cert to directory in which script is located and set verification to true but same errors.

   > curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
   >
   > curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(**FILE**) . '/cacert.pem');

I would like to know if there is something I'm not doing right here because the errors I keep receiving are always the same regardless of the changes I make and it all points to

```
$fgetfiles = file_get_contents( ( string ) $item -> enclosure -> attributes() -> url); //Line 77
```

I'm currently running this on Nginx + PHP-FPM. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you using a self-signed certificate?

Comment: yes i am using a self-signed certificate, I made one when I installed WHM/Cpanel on the server, I made another one as well when I switched from Apache to Nginx..